# How to slide a view in and out in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm trying to make a view *(Linear view with some buttons in - `R.id.playerControl`)* slide in and out based on the context of other events in the activity.

For this purpose I've got a `selectMediaItem` method which should show or hide the view when the user selects or deselects an item respectively.

I'm new with animation in android and I'm having trouble getting this to work for two reasons:

1. The view remains on screen outside the animation time, so when it has finished sliding out it jumps back in - then when requested to slide in it jumps out to slide back in.
2. There is a permanent black space on the screen as the view disappears.  I'd like the view to fill space when when visible and be `GONE` when not.  To this end I'd like the layout to change with the animation as well so that it appears to push other things out of the way.

My Code:

```
protected void selectMediaItem( ItemHandle item ) {

    if (item != null) {
        if (toPlay == null) {
            View playerControl = findViewById(R.id.playerControl);
            Animation slideInAdmination = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in);
            playerControl.startAnimation(slideInAdmination);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (toPlay != null) {
            View playerControl = findViewById(R.id.playerControl);
            Animation slideInAdmination = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out);
            playerControl.startAnimation(slideInAdmination);
        }
    }
    toPlay = item;
}
```

slide_in.xml

```
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />


</set>
```

Is there a simple way to slide a view into place and slide it out again?

Answer (score 5):

I would highly suggest you to use [Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html). Your sample code would be like.

```
mSlidInAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSlidingView, "translationY", 0);
mSlidInAnimator.setDuration(200);
mSlidInAnimator.start();

mSlidOutAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSlidingView, "translationY", newPosOfView);
mSlidOutAnimator.setDuration(200);
mSlidOutAnimator.start();
```

"translationY" means up/down animation. Use "translationX" for right left animation.

Here newPosOfView would be a position relative to your default position of view. For example if you want to move your view 50dp down, it would be 50dp in pixels. In slideInAnimator, pos is 0 because you want to move to orignal position of view.

Read the documentation carefully, its very helpful.

Comment: Although this is an alternate solution and I respect it, it is not an answer to the original question. According to the google documentation, we should be able to use View Animation. It is not deprecated, so there should be an answer to this question.

Comment: I'm not quite certain I follow your logic.  "Being able to us it" and "Being able to use it for ..." are two subtly different statements.  Have you seen something which states it should fulfil these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
slideInAdmination.setFillerAfter(true)
```

before you call `startAnimation()`. This Causes the view to remain in its new position after the animation.